# Cloud Haskell - How to write "pure" for Closures?

Tags: haskell, serialization, cloud-haskell

I've been playing with [Cloud Haskell](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/). I've noticed [in the hackage documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-static-0.3.8/docs/Control-Distributed-Static.html#t:Closure) there's a kind of applicative interface. But in particular I'm trying to find or write a function `closurePure` with the following signature:

```
closurePure :: (Typeable a, Binary a) => a -> Closure a
```

This is basically a restricted version of pure.

Whilst the `Closure` datatype itself is abstract, the following [`closure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-static-0.3.8/docs/Control-Distributed-Static.html#v:closure) provided:

```
closure :: Static (ByteString -> a) -> ByteString -> Closure a
```

So I can get this far:

```
closurePure :: (Typeable a, Binary a) => a -> Closure a
closurePure x = closure ??? (encode x)
```

The problem is what to put where the `???`s are.

My first attempt was the following:

```
myDecode :: (Typeable a, Binary a) => Static (ByteString -> a)
myDecode = staticPtr (static decode)
```

But upon reading the [GHC docs on static pointers](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#static-semantics-of-static-pointers), the `show` example suggested to me that you can't have a constraint because a constrained function doesn't have a `Typeable` instance. So I tried the work around suggested using [`Dict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9.1/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict):

```
myDecode :: Typeable a => Static (Dict (Binary a) -> ByteString -> a)
myDecode = staticPtr (static (\Dict -> decode))
```

But now I've got the wrong type that doesn't fit into the `closure` function above.

Is there anyway to write `closurePure` or something similar (or have I missed it in the Cloud Haskell docs)? Raising `binary` plain types to `Closure`s seems essential to using the applicative interface given, but I can't work out how to do it.

Note that I can do this:

```
class StaticDecode a where
  staticPtrDecode :: StaticPtr (ByteString -> a)

instance StaticDecode Int where
  staticPtrDecode = static Data.Binary.decode

instance StaticDecode Float where
  staticPtrDecode = static Data.Binary.decode

instance StaticDecode Integer where
  staticPtrDecode = static Data.Binary.decode

-- More instances etc...

myPure :: forall a. (Typeable a, StaticDecode a, Binary a) => a -> Closure a
myPure x = closure (staticPtr staticPtrDecode) (encode x)
```

Which works well but basically requires me to repeat an instance for each `Binary` instance. It seems messy and I'd prefer another way.

Comment: Are you sure `myDecode = staticPtr (static decode)` doesn't work? It seems to me that you just traded the `Binary` constraint for a `StaticDecode` constraint, but you say it's working.

Comment: Sorry, the last function should be called `myPure`, not `myDecode`. Hopefully that makes more sense. But in a sense you're right, but inside the `StaticDecode` instance I'm calling static (which works) but when I grab `decode` first from the Binary instance then apply static it fails. 

I'm guessing (this is entirely a guess) that each instance of `StaticDecode` generates a unique static pointer so this works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, `Closure` has an applicative-*like* structure, a fact made even more explicit in both the interface and the implementation of [distributed-closure](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-closure-0.3.4.0/docs/Control-Distributed-Closure.html). It's not quite applicative, because in the `pure` case we do have the additional constraint that the argument must somehow be serializable.

Actually, we have a stronger constraint. Not only must the argument be serializable, but the constraint must itself be serializable. Just like it's hard to serialize functions directly, you can imagine that it's hard to serialize constraints. But just like for functions, the trick is to serialize a *static pointer* to the constraint itself, if such a static pointer exists. How do we know that such a pointer exists? We could introduce a type class with a single method that gives us the name of the pointer, given a constraint:

```
class GimmeStaticPtr c where
  gimmeStaticPtr :: StaticPtr (Dict c)
```

There's a slight technical trick going on here. The kind of the type index for `StaticPtr` is the kind `*`, whereas a constraint has kind `Constraint`.  So we reuse a trick from the [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) library that consists in wrapping a constraint into a data type (`Dict` above), which like all data types is of kind `*`. Constraints that have an associated `GimmeStaticPtr` instance are called *static constraints*.

In general, it's sometimes useful to compose static constraints to get more static constraints. `StaticPtr` is not composable, but `Closure` is. so what `distributed-closure` actually does is define a similar class, that we'll call,

```
class GimmeClosure c where
  gimmeClosure :: Closure (Dict c)
```

Now we can define `closurePure` in a similar way that you did:

```
closurePure :: (Typeable a, GimmeClosure (Binary a)) => a -> Closure a
```

It would be great if in the future, the compiler could resolve `GimmeClosure` constraints on-the-fly by generating static pointers as needed. But for now, the thing that comes closest is Template Haskell. distributed-closure provides a module to autogenerate `GimmeClosure (Cls a)` constraints at the definition site for class `Cls`. See `withStatic` [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-closure-0.3.4.0/docs/Control-Distributed-Closure-TH.html).

Incidentally, Edsko de Vries gave a [great talk](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/10632-static-pointers-closures-and-polymorphism) about distributed-closure and the ideas embodied therein.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a moment to consider what you are asking for.  Recall that typeclasses are basically shorthand for dictionary passing.  So let's rewrite:

```
data BinaryDict a = BinaryDict 
  { bdEncode :: a -> ByteString
  , bdDecode :: ByteString -> a
  }
```

Now you wish to write a function:

```
closurePure :: (Typeable a) => BinaryDict a -> a -> Closure a
```

Your attempt is:

```
closurePure bdict = closure (staticPtr (static (bdDecode bdict))) . bdEncode bdict
```

Now that we can see what's going on explicitly, we can see that `static`'s argument cannot be closed.  If `BinaryDict`s were allowed to be created willy nilly, say from user data, this function would be impossible.  We would instead need:

```
closurePure :: (Typeable a) => Static (BinaryDict a) -> a -> Closure a
```

That is, we need entries for the needed `Binary` instances in the static pointer table.  Hence your enumeration solution, and why I suspect that such a solution is required.  We also can't expect to enumerate it *too* automatically, because there are infinitely many instances.

It seems silly to me, however, since instances seem like just the sorts of things that you would want to be static automatically.  They are static by nature (what's that, [`reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection)? I can't hear you).  This was probably at least ruminated about in the distributed Haskell papers (I haven't read them).

We could solve this problem in general by simply creating a class that concretely enumerates every instance of every class ([déjà vu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/scrap-your-boilerplate-a-practical-approach-to-generic-programming/)?).

```
class c => StaticConstraint c where
    staticConstraint :: StaticPtr (Dict c)
instance StaticConstraint (Show Int) where
    staticConstraint = static Dict
-- a handful more lines...
```

Somewhat more seriously, if you really don't want to enumerate (I don't blame you), you can at least ease the pain with a calling convention:

```
closurePure :: (Typeable a, Binary a) => StaticPtr (ByteString -> a) -> a -> Closure a
closurePure decodePtr = closure (staticPtr decodePtr) . encode

someClosure :: Closure Int
someClosure = closurePure (static decode) 42
```

This nonsense is necessary because `static` is a "syntactic form" rather than a function -- by mentioning it, we indicate that the `Binary` instance for `Int` must actually be generated and recorded in the static pointer table.

If you are feeling cheeky you could enable `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` and

```
-- PURE :: (Binary a, Typeable a) => a -> Closure a, I promise
#define PURE (closurePure (static decode))

someClosure :: Closure Int
someClosure = PURE 42
```

Maybe someday Haskell will take the next step and graduate to the time-tested `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` of its predecessors instead of spouting off those arrogant type errors.